# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:15)

Tags: java, eclipse

I cant run my Class project. And I have no cure for this, can someone please help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yr8J.png

```
import java.util.Random;


public class HelloWorld {

    public static String[] intensities = { "00", "33", "66", "99", "CC", "FF" };

    public static String randomColor() {
        Random a = new Random();
        return "#" + intensities[a.nextInt(6)] + intensities[a.nextInt(6)]
                + intensities[a.nextInt(6)];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nRows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int nCols = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        String[] colArray = new String[10];
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            colArray[c] = randomColor();
        }
        System.out.println("<table border='1'>\n");
        for (int i = 1; i <= nRows; i++) {
            System.out.println("<tr>");
            for (int j = 1; j <= nCols; j++) {
                int result = i * j;
                int colorNum = result * 10 / (nRows * nCols +1);
                System.out.println("<td bgcolor='" + colArray[colorNum] + "'>"
                        + result + "</td>");

            }
            System.out.println("</tr>\n");
        }
        System.out.println("</table>");

    }
}
```

I cant run my Class project. And I have no cure for this, can someone please help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yr8J.png

Comment: Please do some research and take the time to post a question instead of a link to a picture showing text.

Comment: Why did you decide to post picture instead of text?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Pshemo At least he did not link a powerpoint file with the picture of the source code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called the program without arguments and you are trying to read an empty arguments array.

Comment: Thanks for helping, how do I change this? :) 
Im really new to this, sorry to bother.